# Missing artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.14.59

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven

My pom.xml file

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>zed.exiote</groupId>
  <artifactId>AMZNtoHH</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have been trying to download selenium in Eclipse using Maven but this error keeps showing up

*(Missing artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.14.59)*

I can't build or compile anything until this error is resolved

I'm new to Eclipse Selenium and Maven so I really don't know whats going on.

Comment: "(Missing artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.14.59)" -->  If this is the message you are seeing then you have given the version incorrectly for artifact: selenium-java. The right version (as mentioned in your pom and on maven's site) is 3.141.59. If you still face the same issue, it would help to share the complete pom to help re-create the issue on our side.

Comment: The error indicates a different version from your pom.xml (and [3.14.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java) doesn't exist)

Comment: Ya you're right it was the version. However I did fix it to the correct version but it didn't update until I rebooted the IDE. I don't know why I have to but I guess eclipse wants me to reboot the IDE every time I update my pom.xml and add new dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**so you should try to check in pom.xml:**

1. Check if the correct repository is specified in the pom.xml from
   which the package was downloaded originally. It might happen that
   the url in pom.xml is not correct and you have the required jar file
   in the .m2 repository.
2. Check for the artifact version, if the version specified in the
   pom.xml is there in the repository from where it should be
   downloaded.
3. Check if the jar is missing or not. If yes, place it manually in the
   .m2 repository. Sometimes the jar mentioned in the pom.xml is not
   downloaded and it gives error.
4. You can also try deleting the entire .m2 repository folder and run
   the maven build. The jars get downloaded from scratch. It might
   resolve the problem as well.